# How is SSRS report Deployed to remote server in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

How is SSRS report deployed in the remote production server where there will be no connection between prod/ staging & production server? you can only send some staff to prod server.

What are the steps ?

What measure should we take to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a more detailed explanation of your server stages and requirements I'd suggest you need a PowerShell script or SP Timer Job  to send your published content between servers.

Comment: servers has no link or no relation. you have to take staffs separately? PowerShell script or SP Timer Job both will not in this case.